# Downloading an apk, with not such file or directory error..

Tags: java, android, download

I'm creating an app which downloads an apk file from a webserver then it installs it, but I'm having a problem, when I click download, the progress bar compares but it doesn't change, and in the Android Monitor compares this:
[image: Error displayed]

I am using an avd with android 7.1.1, and I'm going to try with marshmallow. 
this is the code:

```
    try {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
   String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";

                    mSavePath = sdPath + "updateDownload";
                    File dir = new File(mSavePath);

                    if (!dir.exists())
                        if (dir.mkdir())
                            Log.d(TAG, "mkdir success");
                        else
                            Log.d(TAG, "mkdir failed!");

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();
                    conn.connect();

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    int length = conn.getContentLength();

                    File apkFile = new File(mSavePath, version_name);

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(apkFile);

                    int count = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while (!isCancel) {
                        int numread = is.read(buffer);
                        count += numread;
                        mProgress = (int) ((float) (count / length) * 100);

                        mUpdateProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(DOWNLOADING);
                        if (numread < 0) {
                            mUpdateProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(DOWNDLOAD_FINISHED);
                            break;
                        }
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, numread);

                    }
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, " Media not mounted");
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Can you check if "updateDownload" directory exist?

Comment: no, it doesn't exist..

Comment: There you go.. you should create it if it does not exist :)

Comment: I did,with this:
         if (!dir.exists())
                        if (dir.mkdir())
                            Log.d(TAG, "mkdir success");
                        else
                            Log.d(TAG, "mkdir failed!");

Comment: and yet the directory does not exist. what does your log says about mkdir , also put some logs to show the full path, this will help you debug it

Answer (score 1):

Android Need runtime Permission after Android 6.0
refer https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html